# jQuery - Get Total value of the next options in a dropdown after the selected one based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

HTML Output

```
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="3"> -  - Child task</option>
```

jQuery Code to fetch value of next option:

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected').next().data('task-hours');
```

Tried looping for multiple child task(s) but its not working:

```
var foo = [];
$('#dropDownId :selected').each(function(i, selected){
  foo[i] = $(selected).data('task-hours');
});
```

How can I fetch total/combined value of next options after the selected one ?

In above case total value should be `50 (child 1) + 50 (child 2) = 100 (parent task)` i.e. **child task(s) total value should not exceed the value of parent task**

Comment: is it just two level deep or there could be more?

Comment: @Jai it could be more. Unless child taks hours do not exceed parent task hours, user can have more.

Comment: How do you know an `option` is a child task ? Because of double `- -` ?

Comment: That is to notify the end user who is child and who is parent. But when you select parent task `var childtaskHours = $('#dropDownId option:selected').next().data('task-hours');` gives me next option value which is a child task obviously. This is working for a single child task but not for multiple.

Comment: You need to add an identifier to distinguish between parent and child tasks

Comment: Indeed, in that case, you cannot have another parent task

Comment: So what would happen if somebody selects a child task?

Comment: @billyonecan, I agree, the code posted by Brewal works for only parent task. But how could we break down Child Task hours i.e. `50` can further be break down to `25+25` ?

Comment: @billyonecan is there a better way to distinguish parent and child task which can be further break down to sub-child task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) method for this :

```
var selectedOption = $('#dropDownId option:selected')
var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.data('task-hours');
var sum = 0;
selectedOption.nextAll().each(function(){
    if (sum < selectedOptionValue) {
        sum += $(this).data('task-hours');
    } else {
        sum = selectedOptionValue;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you loop it.First get the selected value.Then run the loop like below.

Note : below is not error free code , Its just like alogirthm or steps.

```
var startfrom = $('#dropDownId option:selected').attr('value');

var alltext = "";
$('option').each(function(key,attr) {
{
if(key<startfrom) return;
alltext += attr.text;

}

console.log(alltext);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropDownId").on('change', function () {
    var a=$('#dropDownId option:selected+option').attr('data-task-hours');
    var b=$("#dropDownId option:selected").attr('data-task-hours');
    var c=Number(a)+Number(b);
    alert(c);
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pmqd5d/2/)**

Comment: Satinder singh: We need to get total value. If two child then val is `100` and if then its `50`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 var sum=0;
 alert($('select option:first').attr('data-task-hours'))
 $('select option:gt(0)').each(function(){
  sum+= parseInt($(this).attr('data-task-hours'));
 });
 if($('select option:first').attr('data-task-hours')==sum){
  alert("parent and children have same hours");
}
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this? Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/st0zkq01/)

```
var sOpt = $("#sel option:selected");
var nextOpts = sOpt.nextAll();
var sum = 0;
nextOpts.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data("taskHours");
});
if ( sum > sOpt.data("taskHours") ) {
    alert ("Total is greater than parent");
} else {
    alert (sum);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option data-task-hours="100" value="1" selected="selected"> - Parent Task</option>
    <option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task</option>
    <option data-task-hours="50" value="3"> -  - Child task</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var indexOfSelected = $("#dropDownId option:selected").index()
 var options = $("#dropDownId option")

 var children = options.slice(indexOfSelected + 1, options.length)

 total = 0
 $.each(children, function(){
     total += $(this).data("task-hours")
 });

console.log("Total sum of children: " + total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pmqd5d/3/)

```
$("#dropDownId").on('change', function () {
    var one=$('#dropDownId option:selected+option').attr('data-task-hours');
    var onetwo=$("#dropDownId option:selected").attr('data-task-hours');
    var onethree=Number(one)+Number(onetwo);
    console.log(onethree);
});
```